# Why doesn't this javascript code work?

Tags: javascript

```
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName(body);
bod.innerHTML = "Hi";
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns an array of elements, not an element.

Comment: Try this document.body.innerHTML = "Hi";

Comment: @Marc - It returns a `NodeList`, not an array :)

Comment: if you haven't already, check out the stack-exchange proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). Something you might find useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are missing quotes:**

```
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName(body);
 ----------------------------------------^
```

Try this with addition of `[0]` at the end to get the `body` itself rather than `NodeList` return by `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
bod.innerHTML = "Hi";
```

Or you can go for this shorter version:

```
var bod = document.body;
bod.innerHTML = "Hi";
```

Or even shorter:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Hi";
```

Comment: To be clear, that's *not* an array, it's *like* an array, it's actually a `NodeList`.

Answer (score 4):

1-> you have to provide a tagName as a string

2-> you have to pick the first element of the returned (nodeList) collection

```
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
bod.innerHTML = "Hi";
```

Comment: Noticed strange behavior of the SO-editor here: after a numbered list formatting code doesn't work anymore, hence ->.

Answer (score 1):

Because the getElementsByTagName() method returns a NodeList of all a elements with a specified name. In other word this return an List (something like array), so you need to get it first element in this case.

```
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
bod.innerHTML = "Hi";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Hi";
```